# Redirect to Index.html issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On click i want to go to index.html for example if user click reload icon in browser it would redirect to index.html right samething by using ng-click.
How to achieve this in angular js

HTML:

```
<div ng="logoutcntrl">
    <ons-button ng-click="logout()"></ons-button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function logoutcntrl($scope){
  $scope.logout= function(){
    $location.path="index.html";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use browsers native `window.location` object and its `href` property:

```
function logoutcntrl($scope) {
  $scope.logout= function() {
    window.location.href = "index.html";
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually there is a `$window` service in AngularJS. It's better to use since it's replacable and can be mocked for testing: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window